# How to pass DataFrame as input to Spark UDF?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe and I want to apply a function to each row. This function depends of other dataframes.

Simplified example. I have three dataframes like below:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ['a', 'b', 1],
    ['c', 'd', 3]
    ]).toDF(('feat1', 'feat2', 'value'))

df_other_1 = sc.parallelize([
        ['a', 0, 1, 0.0],
        ['a', 1, 3, 0.1],
        ['a', 3, 10, 1.0],
        ['c', 0, 10, 0.2],
        ['c', 10, 25, 0.5]
        ]).toDF(('feat1', 'lower', 'upper', 'score'))

df_other_2 = sc.parallelize([
        ['b', 0, 4, 0.1],
        ['b', 4, 20, 0.5],
        ['b', 20, 30, 1.0],
        ['d', 0, 5, 0.05],
        ['d', 5, 22, 0.9]
        ]).toDF(('feat1', 'lower', 'upper', 'score'))
```

For each row of `df`, I want to collect the unique upper values for `feat1` and `feat2` from `df_other_1` and `df_other_2`, i.e. for first row, the unique values are (1, 3, 10, 4, 20, 30). Then, I'll sort them like (30, 20, 10, 4, 3, 1) and add to the front, one number above the first one. The `df` would become like so:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
        ['a', 'b', 1, [31, 30, 20, 10, 4, 3, 1]],
        ['c', 'd', 3, [26, 25, 22, 10, 5]]
        ]).toDF(('feat1', 'feat2', 'value', 'lst'))
```

Then, for each row of `df` and for each of the respective values of the `lst`, I want to calculate the sum of `score` from both `df_other_1` and `df_other_2` where each value of `lst` falls within `upper` and `lower`. My goal is to find the lowest value in each `lst` whose total score is above some threshold (e.g. 1.4).

Here's how to calculate the total score. So, for the first row of `df`, the first value of `lst` is 31. In `df_other_1` for `feat1`, it is above the highest bucket so it would get a score of 1. Same for `df_other_2`. So, the total score would be 1+1 =2. For the value of 10 (again for the first row), the total score would be 1 + 0.5 = 1.5.

This is how the `df` would look like in the end:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
            ['a', 'b', 1, [31, 30, 20, 10, 4, 3, 1], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.1, 0.2], 4],
            ['c', 'd', 3, [26, 25, 22, 10, 5], [2.0, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1.1], 25]
            ]).toDF(('feat1', 'feat2', 'value', 'lst', 'total_scores', 'target_value'))
```

I'm actually looking to find these target values `4` and `25`. The intermediate steps do not really matter.

==========================================================================

Here's what I tried so far:

```
def get_threshold_for_row(feat1, feat2, threshold):

    this_df_other_1 = df_other_1.filter(col('feat1') == feat1)
    this_df_other_2 = df_other_2.filter(col('feat1') == feat2)

    values_feat_1 = [i[0] for i in this_df_other_1.select('upper').collect()]
    values_feat_1.append(values_feat_1[-1] + 1)
    values_feat_2 = [i[0] for i in this_df_other_2.select('upper').collect()]
    values_feat_2.append(values_feat_2[-1] + 1)

    values = values_feat_1 + values_feat_2
    values = list(set(values)) #Keep unique values
    values.sort(reverse=True)  #Sort from largest to smallest

    df_1_score = df_2_score = 0
    prev_value = 10000 #Any large number
    prev_score = 10000

    for value in values:
        df_1_score = get_score_for_key(this_df_other_1, 'feat_1', feat_1, value)
        df_2_score = get_score_for_key(this_df_other_2, 'feat_1', feat_2, value)

        total_score = df_1_score + df_2_score

        if total_score < threshold and prev_score >= threshold:
            return prev_value

        prev_score = total_score
        prev_value = value


def is_dataframe_empty(df):
    return len(df.take(1)) == 0

def get_score_for_key(scores_df, grouping_key, this_id, value):

    if is_dataframe_empty(scores_df):
        return 0.0

    w = Window.partitionBy([grouping_key]).orderBy(col('upper'))

    scores_df_tmp = scores_df.withColumn("prev_value", lead(scores_df.upper).over(w))\
                        .withColumn("is_last", when(col('prev_value').isNull(), 1).otherwise(0))\
                        .drop('prev_value')

    scores_df_tmp = scores_df_tmp.withColumn("next_value", lag(scores_df_tmp.upper).over(w))\
                        .withColumn("is_first", when(col('next_value').isNull(), 1).otherwise(0))\
                        .drop('next_value').cache()

    grouping_key_score = scores_df_tmp.filter((col(grouping_key) == this_id) & 
                              (((value >= col('from_value')) & (value < col('to_value'))) | 
                                ((value >= col('to_value')) & (col('is_last') == 1)) |
                                ((value < col('from_value')) & (col('is_first') == 1)) |
                                (col('from_value').isNull()))) \
                    .withColumn('final_score', when(value <= col('to_value'), col('score')).otherwise(1.0)) \
                    .collect()[0]['final_score']

    return grouping_key_score

df.rdd.map(lambda r: (r['feat_1'], r['feat_2'])) \
    .map(lambda v: (v[0], v[1], get_threshold_for_row(v[0], v[1], 1.4)))
    .toDF()
```

But I'm getting:
`AttributeError: 'Py4JError' object has no attribute 'message'`

Sorry for the long post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I have a dataframe and I want to apply a function to each row. This function depends of other dataframes.

**tl;dr** That is not possible in UDFs.

In the most broader sense, a UDF is a function (a Catalyst expression actually) that accepts zero or more column values (as Column references).

A UDF can only work on records that could in the most broader case be an entire DataFrame if the UDF is a user-defined aggregate function (UDAF).

If you want to work on more than one DataFrame in a UDF you have to `join` the DataFrames to have the columns you want to use for the UDF.