# Pyspark not able to process data using UDF funtion

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having 2 dataframe

df1:

[image: df1]

df2:

[image]

Created function to get the relevant data but its throwing error:

```
def get_coded_values(df, field_id, lang_id, udv_str):
    udc_code = udv_str.split()
    print(udc_code)
    selected_df = df.select("data1").where((df.field_id == field_id) & (df.language == lang_id) & (df.udc_code.isin(udc_code)))
    if selected_df.count()>0:
        return selected_df.select(selected_df.columns[0]).first()[0]
    else:
        return None

get_coded_values_udf = udf(get_coded_values, StringType())

df_with_modified_column = df1.withColumn("ModifiedName", get_coded_values_udf(df2,df1.field_id,df1.language,df1.udv_string))
```

Please help me to resolve the below error:

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[data1: string, field_id: int, language: int, json_udc_code: string, udc_code: string] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You cannot pass a dataframe to a udf. See this existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509249/how-to-pass-dataframe-as-input-to-spark-udf. Have you tried joining the dataframes on field_id to make it easier?